# iOS Loading Data From A Web Server - Best Practices?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6

I've been working on my first iOS app and I finally have something that works like I intended. This app reads in an XML file, parses that data and displays what needs to be listed - a list of profiles actually. What I want to do know is have the app check a web service (I'll code this in PHP) and retrieve this XML file.

So my question are: What is the best practice for handling this? Should I keep my data in an XML file or use something else (JSON I think)? What are the standard approaches a more experience developer would take?

What I envision is there's a web site that a user can enter their information in, which then stores their profile information in a database. Then the web service simply pulls this data and provides it to the phone.

Comment: For new developers, YouTube is your friend.  [This is the one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2tUxV_66Q4U&feature=related) I found most useful for XML parsing.

Comment: If you already got the NSXMLParser working, that's the hardest part.  The first part of the tutorial I linked goes though how to send a request to a Webserver and what to do with the response to send it to your parser.  I haven't used JSON, but I know there are tutorials for that all over YouTube too.

Answer (score 1):

Whether it is json or xml, never retrieve data on main thread. It'll make your app's UI unresponsive.

Her is two tutorials which will help you alot.

1. [JSON](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5)
2. [XML](http://wiki.cs.unh.edu/wiki/index.php/Parsing_XML_data_with_NSXMLParser)